# Date picker not visible on SSRS report for some users on both Chrome and IE

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-365

We have 365 customer engagement organization, some users (around 3 users out of 50 users) has a strange issue. Date time parameters doesn't have a date picker displayed. The date fields are displayed as normal text inputs. As you can see in the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

**we tried to login with different user on the same machine and using the same browser and the fields are displayed correctly:**

Please note the following:

- Different user on the same machine and on the same browser, the
  picker is working fine and disabled with no issue.
- This on both browsers IE and Google Chrome. And both are working fine for different user.
- This is for all the reports not just one report.
- We tried to fill in the date manually, then we opened SQL Profile and we found out that
  the date is passed to the SQL Server with wrong values than the
  manually entered one, like year 2000 and 2058 years.
- The organization was updated from 2011 organization and it is working
  fine for the same users on 2011.
- We didn't find any errors in the SSRS server or the Dynamics CRM server.
- We tried to give these users more permissions on the SSRS server on the reports folder and the
  same issue.
- We delete the report and uploaded it again to the CRM and the same issue.
- We are using SQL Server and SSRS 2012 version.

So what we can do, is is a bug or what?!

Update:

The warnings displayed in the developer tools in console panel:

[image]

Comment: Does the user it's not working for have the User-Agent Switcher extension in Google Chrome? If you press `F12` in Google Chrome to open the developer tools do you see any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning No this extension is not installed, but it is the same issue on IE as well. I check the console panel only warning about devtools and another warning as well (I will add screenshot in the question). But these are the same warning displayed in the machine for other users who doesn't have the issue and the reports are working fine.

Comment: What’s those three user experience in another machine? Just to make sure is it machine and user profile specific issue? If it works for them in a different machine, then it could be confirmed.

Comment: @ArunVinoth No still the same issue. In my machine, my account works fine, in the same browser, I signed out, signed in with one of these users with the issue and it is not working. So, it is probably something to do with their user accounts, the system admin reviewed their domain users and all has the same exact permissions like my user and other users who are working fine.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal hmm interesting. Since you’re in on-Prem, can you try to refresh the user profile for those 3 users - like change the domain name to somebody who is not in the system and save it. Then you can rollback afterwards. Ex. domain\user1 to domain\userx

Comment: I would upgrade SQL Server - the browser support is much improved from SQL Server 2016 onwards, and there are many UI improvements. Also SQL Server 2012 fell out of mainstream support years ago, so if this was a bug it will never be patched.

Comment: @ArunVinoth See my answer below, it is very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the language under user's personalized settings did the trick and solved the issue. The working users had Arabic(Egypt) language, whereas the users with the issue had Arabic (Saudi Arabia), because this is the language pack we installed. Changing the user language to Arabic Egypt solved the issue, I don't know whey!

Comment: wow good catch. I assumed you verified these before :)

Comment: Which was the installed language pack? `Arabic (Egypt)` or `Arabic (Saudi Arabia)`?

Comment: @jasonscript Old CRM 2011 we had Arabic Egypt, when we did the migration, we only found Arabic language option for 365 Customer Engagement, which is Saudi Arabia. There is no option to choose Arabic Egypt, I don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

Arabic (Saudi Arabia) wasn't installed that's why it is not handling it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question already has an accepted answer. Please try to only answer questions that don't have an accepted answer, or where the accepted answer is significantly different from your own.